# Title not showing on AngularJS (directive inside a directive)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive inside another directive using AngularJS. The title that is called ( {{questions.n3A.name}} ), is not being displayed.

Here's my js:

```
.directive('myRating', function() {

return{
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div><div class="row question">{{questions.n3A.name}}</div> \
              <div class="row rating" ng-controller="RatingDemoCtrl"> \
                <rating value="rate" max="max" readonly="isReadonly" state-on="\'glyphicon-star rated\'" state-off="\'glyphicon-star\'"></rating> \
                  <div class="col-md-12"> \
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger form-control" ng-click="rate = 0" ng-disabled="isReadonly">Clear</button> \
                  </div>  \
              </div> \
              </div>',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        text: '@'
    }
};


});

$scope.questions = {
"n3A": {
  "name": "How safe did you feel on your trip?",
  "ID": "n3A"
},
"n3B": {
  "name": "How did you get there?",
  "ID": "n3B"
},
```

};

I also made a [Pluncker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aYbtFYvKo3Y4SXAud5mA?p=preview). When clicking on Yes and South America/Asia/Africa, the title should display on top of the stars.

Any idea of what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an isolated scope of the directive with `scope: {text: '@'}`

That way, directive has no idea about what `scope.questions` variable refers to.

If you remove `scope` property out of `myRating` directive declaration, it will work